# Any way to convert Realm database file in to sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, realm

I have realm database `(.realm)` from an existing application, which has more than 400k records.

I dug my head in to this for more than 3-4 hours, but I couldn't find any fruitful results towards converting a `.realm` file in to a **sqlite** file.

Comment: We have found little value in Realm for our specific use-case, and it bloats our APK, making it harder to create an Instant App. I'm also looking for a way to convert a Realm database file to another format (possibly sqlite) -- without the Realm SDK. I want to be able to access legacy data in a Realm file from a newer version of our app where Realm libs are gone. So far, I've had no luck finding a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any data conversion so far has been done manually. People have converted from Core Data to Realm by grabbing the objects from Core Data and then saving them to a Realm.

I imagine your best bet will be similar here. Grab each object from the Realm and then convert it to the tables/rows/and columns in sqlite. Then you can take that file anywhere.

Comment: You are absolutely right but i was thinking if there is any better and quick way to do the same because i am beginner for realm i didn't use it as before.

Comment: Currently there isnt a quick way, what are you trying to do? Are you creating this file and then passing it to the server?

Comment: i having requirement to use database with encryption. Original database is in Relam format.  Relam don't support encryption at the moment and i have only one option of Sqlite left for me to make this task possible.

Comment: I see, just to clarify, Realm does support encryption but its a local database, so you still would need to take care of things on the server.

Comment: @yoshyosh for example if you get tired of it in the future and decide to get back to SQLite :).

Answer (score 1):

You can open the realm file in Realm Browser & there you have the option to convert the file in to CSV ( File => Export => CSV ). Then you can import that CSV file to mysql database.

If you want sqlite more specifically, You can import tables separately to your sqlite db through [SQLiteBrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) . Create or open your database file and select the specific table you want , then you can import table from CSV.