# Migrate from Realm to Room

Tags: android, realm, android-room

The title says it all.  The company I work for prefers native solutions over 3rd party and now that room is "prime time" they'd like us to migrate over.  What's the best way to do this?

I know that I can do a realm query and copy the results into the new database but what I'm looking for is a way to use the same database file (if that's possible).

I'm new to Room so still looking for the best way. I'm open to any and all suggestions.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure out how to migrate ?

Comment: @ran yeah... a little at a time.  Read the value from realm, write it to room, remove from realm.  Wash, rinse, repeat

Comment: and it worked perfectly ?

Comment: yeah.  It was a pain but it worked

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Realm is in fact NoSQL and Room is as described "an abstraction layer over SQLite". I'm sorry but I really don't think that keeping the same database file is possible. Moreover one of the biggest advantages of Room over Realm is that the size of database is much smaller so it would not be wise also.

But you can search for everything connected with converting realm to sqlite like:
[Any way to convert Realm database file in to sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317258/any-way-to-convert-realm-database-file-in-to-sqlite)
There is plenty of topics like this and it seems not so complicated.

Once you get sqlite database than using Room is just natural.

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks a ton.  I'm getting pretty solid with the queries.  It's the migration that's beginning to scare me

Comment: Little off topic here but pardon me. Prepare yourself for a long journey. Room is still quite young and has some annoying malfunctions (eg db encryption, db managment etc). Been there, done that.